# Preventing line break in figure caption

Tags: floats, captions, line-breaking, citing, line-spacing

I have the following figure with the corresponding caption:[image]

As you can see the caption inappropriately breaks the line, which I want to avoid. Optimally without simply reducing the font size of the caption text.

Code as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {article}
\usepackage[skip=10pt, labelfont=bf, labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[numbers,sort,authoryear]{natbib}
\hypersetup{hidelinks=true}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\mytab}[1]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
#1
\end{tabular}
}
\begin{figure} [h!]
\label{fig: timeline}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (11,0);
\foreach \x in {0.8,4,5.5,7,10.2}
\draw(\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm, -3pt);
\draw (0.8,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_0$};
\draw (4,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_1$};
\draw (5.5,0) node[below=3pt] {$0$};
\draw (7,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_2$};
\draw (10.2,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_3$};
\draw (2.35,0) node[above=12pt, align=center] {
                            $\left(\mytab{estimation \\ window}\right]$};
\draw (5.5,0) node[above=12pt, align=center]{
                            $\left(\mytab{event \\ window}\right]$};
\draw(8.65,0) node[above=12pt, align=center]{
                            $\left(\mytab{post-event \\ window}\right]$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Time Line for an Event Study (\cite{campbell1996}, p. 157})
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{./references}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should put the last parenthesis in the caption. It is typed after that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Several comments:

- Since you're (i) using the `agsm` bibliography style, which is distributed with the `harvard` citation management package and (ii) loading the `natbib` package rather than the `harvard` package, you should load the `har2nat` package as well. As its name indicates, it "translates" various macros that are defined by the `harvard` package (and which are used in `agsm.bst`) into equivalent `natbib` macros.
- You're currently loading the `natbib` package with the options `numbers`, `sort`, and `authoryear`. You should drop the first two options: The `agsm` style is meant for authoryear-style citation callouts -- pointless to try to use it with numeric-style citation callouts; the `sort` option only makes sense if `numbers` is the callout style.
- Now to the main point of your query: You ought to write the `\caption` command as

  ```
  \caption{Time Line for an Event Study \citep[p.~157]{campbell1996}}
  ```

  Note the use of the `~` ("tie") character, which acts like an unbreakable space character.
- Two minor points: (i) The `\label` instruction should come *after* the `\caption` instruction -- especially if you want to be able to cross-reference the figure elsewhere in the document. (ii) Use of `\begin{center}...\end{center}` adds a lot of (vertical) whitespace; use the `\centering` directive instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{campbell1996,
  author = "John Y. Campbell and Andrew W. Lo and A. Craig McKinlay",
  title  = "The Econometrics of Financial Markets",
  year   = 1996,
  publisher = "Princeton University Press",
  address = "Princeton NJ",
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[skip=10pt, labelfont=bf, labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{har2nat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks=true}

\newcommand{\mytab}[1]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
#1
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure} [h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (11,0);
\foreach \x in {0.8,4,5.5,7,10.2}
\draw(\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm, -3pt);
\draw (0.8,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_0$};
\draw (4,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_1$};
\draw (5.5,0) node[below=3pt] {$0$};
\draw (7,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_2$};
\draw (10.2,0) node[below=3pt] {$T_3$};
\draw (2.35,0) node[above=12pt, align=center] {
                            $\left(\mytab{estimation \\ window}\right]$};
\draw (5.5,0) node[above=12pt, align=center]{
                            $\left(\mytab{event \\ window}\right]$};
\draw(8.65,0) node[above=12pt, align=center]{
                            $\left(\mytab{post-event \\ window}\right]$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Time Line for an Event Study \protect\citep[p.~157]{campbell1996}} 
\label{fig:timeline}
\end{figure}

A cross-reference to \autoref{fig:timeline}.

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{./references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mico for your help!
The \citep{} command is great.

However using the har2nat package and dropping the numbers and sort options changes my citations to for example:

(Campbell 1996), whereas I'd like to have:

Campbell (1996).

Any idea for that? thanks!

Comment: @marinko - For text-style citations, use `\citet`. The macro `\citep` is for "parenthetic" citations. (In your code, the macro `\cite` is used, which is aliased by `natbib` to function like `\citet`.)

Comment: great, thanks! didn't know this existed!